# How to select name containg a specific letter in the first half of it?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I wonder if you could help me figuring out of how I can select last name of a worker who has letter 'A' in the first half of his last name. By saying half I mean splitting the last name and picking up only the left part of it. For instance, let's take the last name 'Schwarzenegger' containing 15 characters. The query will fetch this last name as it does have letter 'a' in the first half of it (SCHWARZ-negger). If the last name is 'Jordan', then we are not interested in it since letter 'a' appears in the second half of the name (jor-DAN)

Any help or hint would be highly appreciated.

Cheers
Andy

Comment: Does “first part of his last name” mean the very first character? If so, what do you think the first % in your string will do? (Also “not quite right”isn’t very helpful - we can’t see your raw data, current result or desired result...)

Comment: What does *in the first part* mean? Do you mean *starting with 'A'*?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, Alex. Let me provide you an example. I have those last names: Kazlavicius, Adomulis, Sabonis, Zukas, Smetona, Kairys. So the query should fetch me only: Kazlavicius, Adomulis, Sabonis, Kairys because those last names contain letter "A" in the first part of the last name.

Comment: For Names _starting_ with `A` you need to use `LIKE 'A%'`

Comment: All of you examples have an A in the first two characters, so is that the rule? Or in the first *half* of the name? Or something else? Edit your question to show the data, current and desired results - and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do. If you can't explain the rules we can't help you tell them how to implement them.

Comment: I would love to know the reason behind why this is required!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select last_name
from workers
where substr(last_name,1,length(last_name)/2) like '%A%';
```

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: As only you knew the answer and the question/problem, making no sense why you posted the question !!!

Comment: Well, I did not know the answer at first but I figured it out eventually :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use this :

```
select last_name from workers 
where INSTR(lower(last_name, 'a', 1)) > 0 
and INSTR(lower(last_name, 'a', 1)) < 3 ;
```

Comment: These find an A anywhere in the name, not just in 'the first part' (whatever that actually means).

Comment: This is not fully clear actually until he gives us some sample data. Though he gave an answer about data `I have those last names: Kazlavicius, Adomulis, Sabonis, Zukas, Smetona, Kairys. So the query should fetch me only: Kazlavicius, Adomulis, Sabonis, Kairys because those last names contain letter "A" in the first part of the last name.`

Comment: But your queries will all match `Smetona` for instance, which is not one the OP wants to return. We don't know the rules on what should match, but we know some that should not.